Name of Fallacy: Refutation of argument is not refutation of conclusion
Refuting an argument, and refuting an argument's conclusion, are two different things.
For example, the argument:
"Bananas are yellow, therefore, God exists"
can easily be refuted by pointing out that this argument is invalid.  However, that of course does not provide any refutation of its conclusion: pointing out that this argument is bad does not mean that God does not exist.
However, I sometimes see people reason that way: they think that their refutation of an argument does imply that the argument's conclusion is false. Is there a name for this fallacy?

The argument from fallacy is not as common as common talk suggests. In debates, one is expected to present their best case for the conclusion rather than some contrived non-sequiturs. When people identify a fallacy in such argument they validly infer that one has no reason to believe its conclusion based on it. They are then entitled to dismiss the conclusion on pragmatic grounds, which may be loosely phrased as its 'refutation'.

Bananas are yellow is a statement you cannot conclude any thing from that statement other than it is evidently true or not. Just what is your point!!!

I suspect that in real examples of this fallacy, the parts of the argument being refuted are not as unrelated as this absurd example. No one could possibly think that the color of bananas has anything to do with the existence of God (unless they find something in the Bible about banana color).

Will you run that through any spell-checker, the Edit the Questions? Please?

This question is similar to: Is there a name for the fallacy that refuting the argument refutes the conclusion?.

@hb20007  Yes, thanks!  It is indeed the 'Argument from Fallacy', or 'fallacy fallacy' that I was looking for :)

This is referred to as the Argument from fallacy, or the fallacy fallacy:

Argument from fallacy is the formal fallacy of analyzing an argument and inferring that, since it contains a fallacy, its conclusion must be false. It is also called argument to logic (argumentum ad logicam), the fallacy fallacy, the fallacist's fallacy, and the bad reasons fallacy.

